# Any translation invariant Borel measure such that $\mu([0,1))=1$ is identical to the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I want to show that if $\mu$ is a Borel measure with $\mu([0,1))=1$ that is a translation invariant, then $\mu$ is the same as the Lebesgue measure.

How can I do that?

What properties does this measure have to have in order to be Lebesgue?

Comment: Are you looking for a characterization of Lebesgue measure?  Can you add some specifics to this question?

Comment: I want to show that if $\mu$ is a Borel measure with $\mu([0,1))=1$ that is a translation invariant, then $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure.

Comment: This is the uniqueness of Haar Measure.

Comment: Do you mean that in order to show that $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure, I have to use the uniqueness of Haar Measure??

Comment: No, but is is a consequence of that fact.

Comment: So is the only way to show that $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure the uniqueness of Haar Measure?? Isn`t there also an other way, because we havent get taught it...

Comment: Couldn't we show it, by showing that $\mu([a,b))=b-a$ for each $a$ and $b$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer without further information. A few things come to mind:

- The Lebesgue measure is the unique translation invariant regular Radon measure $\mu$ (translation invariant means s.t. $\mu(A)=\mu(x+A)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ measurable) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mu([0,1]^n)=1$ (it is the Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$).
- Two measures agree, if they agree on a generating set of the $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. boxes, Euclidean balls, etc. Take your pick.
- More generally, two measures agree if their integrals wrt. to "enough" functions agree (in the previous point, characteristic functions).

Comment: I want to show that if $\mu$ is a Borel measure with $\mu([0,1))=1$ that is a translation invariant, then $\mu$ is a Lebesque measure. $$$$ So the first identity you mentioned is satisfied, right??

Comment: Can you show that $\mu((a,b))=b-a$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$? @MaryStar

Comment: Do I have to write the interval $(a,b)$ in respect of $[0,1)$ ??

Comment: Simply use the properties of $\mu$ that you have given to some find $\mu([a,b))$. For instance, since $\mu$ is translation invariant and $1+[0,1)=[1,2)$ you know $\mu([1,2))=\mu([0,1))=1$. Also, since it is additive, you know $\mu([0,2))=\mu([0,1))+\mu([1,2))$ etc. I leave the rest up to you.

Comment: I thought the following: $$a+i+[0,1)=[a+i,a+i+1)$$ $$\mu([a+i,a+i+1))=1$$ Therefore, $$\mu([a,b))=\mu(\cup_{i=0}^{b-a-1}[a+i,a+i+1))=\sum \mu([a+i,a+i+1))=\sum 1=b-a$$ Is this correct?? Having shown that $\mu([a,b))=b-a$ do we conclude that $\mu$ is Lebesque measure??

Comment: Your proof is not correct. $b-a$ need not be a natural number.

Comment: Ahaa... What could I do then??

Comment: You need fractional length intervals. For instance also $[0,1]=[0,1/2)\cup[1/2,1)$, similarly $[0,1)=[0,1/n)\cup\cdots\cup[\frac{n-1}{n},1)$. Apply translation invariance and additivity to those. You will get $\mu([0,1/n))=1/n$, this is enough to get $\mu([b,a))=b-a$ for all rational b,a.

Comment: I got stuck right now... How can I get $\mu([a,b))=b-a$ by using that $\mu \left ([0,\frac{1}{n}) \right )=\frac{1}{n}$??

Comment: I think I said enough. Translation invariance, additivity, .. play around. You will see. If you really can't solve it, look it up somewhere, this is a standard problem.

Comment: Could we do it as followed?? $$\mu([0,1/n))=\mu(a+[0,\frac{1}{n}))=\mu([a,a+\frac{1}{n}))=\mu(\frac{1}{n}+[a,a+\frac{1}{n}))=\mu([a+\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{2}{n}))=\dots \\ \mu([a,b))=\mu([a,a+\frac{1}{n}))+\mu([a+\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{2}{n}))+\dots +\mu([b-\frac{1}{n},b))=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\dots +\frac{1}{n}=\frac{((b-a)n)}{n}=b-a$$ Is this correct??

Comment: It's not written down correctly, but you are on the right track. Be careful with $\cdots$.

Comment: I tried it again:
$$[a,b)=[a,a+\frac{1}{n}) \cup [a+\frac{1}{n}, a+\frac{2}{n}) \cup \dots \cup [b-\frac{1}{n}, b) \\ = \cup_{i=0}^{(b-a)n-1}[a+\frac{i}{n}, a+\frac{i+1}{n})$$
Then we have that:
$$\mu([a,b))=\mu \left ( \cup_{i=0}^{(b-a)n-1} [a+\frac{i}{n}, a+\frac{i+1}{n}) \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{(b-a)n-1} \mu \left ( [a+\frac{i}{n}, a+\frac{i+1}{n}) \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{(b-a)n-1}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n} [(b-a)n-1+1]=b-a$$
Is it better now??

Comment: Ok, but you are implicitly assuming $b-a=m/n$, $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: so is it wrong??

Comment: No, then its ok.

Comment: Ok!! So, the measure is Lebesgue because it is a translation invariant and $\mu([a,b))=b-a, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, right??

Comment: What you did until now is only enough for $\mu([a,b))=b-a$ if $b-a\in\mathbb{Q}$. For irrational $b-a$ approximate by rationals and use regularity. Then it follows that $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Could you give me a hint?? I don't have any idea how to apporoximate an irrational number by rationals.. :/

Comment: For instance, take the decimal expansion of your irrational number and truncate it after the $n$th digit behind the decimal point (that is, set all the digits after the $n$th to $0$). The resulting numbers are a rational approximation of your chosen irrational.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!!! :-)